# groovy + shell : Escaping characters

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, groovyshell

I am using Jenkins Pipeline using Groovy sandbox. And i am trying to run a shell script in a groovy sh function.

The original shell script is

```
sed -i 's/sometext/'"${othertext}"'/' filename
```

I am trying to replace a particular text with other text (taken dynamically). The script works fine when executed directly.
But I want to use it in jenkins groovy sh function.

```
sh(script: '<above shell script>',  returnStdout:false)
```

But there is a problem of escaping characters.
I tried this way of escaping character

```
sh (script: '''sed -i 's/sometext/othertext/' filename''', returnStdout:false)
```

It works fine but `othertext` is not taken dynamically.
Can someone please help me in escaping characters with the original script?
Or please suggest any other way of doing this.

Comment: Have you looked at https://gist.github.com/Faheetah/e11bd0315c34ed32e681616e41279ef4 ? That might help understand some of the quirks of the escaping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the inputs from [daggett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1276664/daggett) and [mkobit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/627727/mkobit) and i did few experiments, the following script worked well

```
def l_othertext = sh(script: 'echo ${othertext}', returnStdout: true).trim()
print('l_othertext='+l_othertext)
sh "sed -i 's/sometext/'${l_othertext}'/' filename"
```

Answer (score 0):

if `othertext` is a groovy variable then this should work:

```
def othertext = 'newtext'
sh (script: """sed -i 's/sometext/${othertext}/' filename""", returnStdout:false)
```

Comment: othertext is not groovy variable. It is parameter to jenkins pipeline job. othertext is dynamic.

Comment: Beware of [injection by interpolation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#injection-via-interpolation) when using variables like this. The safer alternative is to use an environment variable (and single quotes around the groovy string)

Answer (score 0):

```
node{
   sh 'sed -i 's/sometext/'"${othertext}"'/' filename'
}
```